# How to create a custom event in VB.NET that checks for when the console finishes reading a line?

Tags: vb.net, events

I am working on a VB.NET project for class, and I need to create an event that runs a sub whenever the console is finished reading a line. How do you code custom events in VB.NET? Or, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do without creating an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an event is required in this case.

As the next line won't execute until the current line is finished, your program will sit on `Console.ReadLine()` until the user has entered whatever needs to be entered. The next line in your code would then be `mysub()`, where `mysub` is the sub you need to run.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.ReadLine()
    mysub()
End Sub

Sub mysub()
    Console.WriteLine("The user has pressed enter.")
    Console.ReadLine() 'keeps console open until the user is ready to exit
End Sub
```